# How to check will 2 triggers collide?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use this part to Instantiate `head`:

```
GameObject refhead = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Head"), new Vector3(1, 1, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
GameObject head = (GameObject)Instantiate(refhead, transform);
```

But how can I check will it collide with `block` or not? I mean, how to check is the block located at the coordinate (x, y, z)? For example, I want to spawn `head` in `(1, 1, 0)` if `head` will collide with `block (trigger)`, I use `y += 1;`. And again need to check is `block trigger` locates in `(1, 2, 0)`? If yes, need to check in `(1, 3, 0)` and etc. If `block` is not here, head will spawn.

Comment: I assume you want to make sure that these two objects don't have overlapping trigger volumes, is that correct? Are the trigger volumes cubes, spheres, or some other shape? Are they always going to be instantiated with `transform.position.z = 0` ?

Comment: I use Collider2D. So, `block` already spawned, and I need to not spawn `head` inside `block`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Added examples for both 2D and 3D physics based code.**

*2D:*

```
public Vector2 topLeftCorner;
public Vector2 bottomRightCorner;
public int layerMask; // Layer mask to check against (optional)
public float minDepth // Only include objects with a Z coordinate (depth) greater than or equal to this value. (optional)
public float maxDepth // Only include objects with a Z coordinate (depth) less than or equal to this value. (optional)


// casts a box using given coordinates and returns all found colliders
Collider2D[] foundColliders = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(topLeftCorner, bottomRightCorner, layerMask, minDepth, maxDepth);

if (foundColliders.Length == 0) {
  // can spawn things
}
```

find more information [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll.html)

*3D:*

A simple way to check this would be using Physics.CheckSphere to check if a GameObject already exists at the specified location before spawning the object.

```
 // define all locations you want to check in order
 public Vector3[] checkPositions;
 // radius to check for, depending on block size
 public float blockSize = 1.0f

 foreach (Vector3 checkPos in checkPositions) {
     if (Physics.CheckSphere (checkPos, blockSize)) {
         // found something
         Debug.Log('cannot spawn here!', checkPos);
     } else {
         // spot is empty, we can spawn
         refhead.transform.position = checkPos;
         head = (GameObject)Instantiate(refhead, parentTransform);
         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `if (!Physics.CheckSphere(new Vector2(nextx, nexty), 0.8f))
            { // spawn }` but it doesn't work :( It doesn't detect object. P.S. `block` parameters - `RB2 (Kinematic)`, `Box Collider 2D (Is Trigger)`

Comment: I see you are using 2D physics instead, considering you are likely using 2D colliders the provided code will not work no. I will update the answer with a 2D example.

Comment: VS underlines  `LayerMask` that it's wrong. Also `Collider2D` doesn't contain `Length`

Comment: `Collider2D foundColliders = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(new Vector2(nextx - 0.5f, nexty - 0.5f), new Vector2(nexty + 0.5f, nexty + 0.5f), ` **LayerMask** `, 1, 2);
                                                                                         if (foundColliders.` **Length** `== 0) { // spawn }`

Comment: I wrote the code off hand so it might have contained some errors while still displaying the general idea. I updated the code again to address some of the issues.

Comment: @Eloren could you elaborate then as to what exactly isn't working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: It don't detect my block

Comment: @Eloren could you then please edit the original question and show how exactly your block is set up? It's possible that maybe the configuration isn't correct.